Visualforce page component fetching data form apex controller
I'm maintining a legacy system which was written in the Visualforce page and I'm stuck in the following scenarios:
I have a VF Page within that page I'm calling a VF Component and within that component I have data table that shows all the records and when the user clicks on the those hyperlink I show the modal popup.
My question is how to retrieve the records by passing the ID  of the record you clicked?
if you look at the below code my modal popup is opening and I'm able to pass the Id (click selected Id) to the modal popup and now I have a valid Id and within the modal form but how would I call apex controller whenever the modal popup opens it?
Here is the detail:
My VF page: (mainDetail)
<apex:page ...
    <div id="tab-scoped-8" class="slds-tabs--scoped__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-employee">
        <c:relatedList_employees employees="{!Employee__c}" />
    </div>
</apex:page>

My VF Component - relatedList_employees:
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="employee" description="This is an array of Employee__c" type="Employee__c[]" />
    
    <apex:repeat value="{!employee}" var="emp">
        <div> 
            <!-- Link to open the modal -->
            <a href="#" onclick="openModal('{!emp.Id}')">View Details</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Component -->
        <c:BaseModalPopup empId="{!emp.Id}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>

VF Component BaseModalPopup:
<apex:component controller="EmployeeController">
    <apex:attribute name="empId" description="Employee Id" type="String" required="true" />

    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <div id="modalOverlay" class="modal-overlay" style="display: none;">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" id="myModal" style="display:none;">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h1 id="modal-title" style="font-size: 26px;">Employee Details</h1>
                </header>

                <!-- Modal Body -->
                <div class="slds-modal__content" style="padding: 20px;">
                    <apex:form>
                        <apex:actionRegion>
                            <apex:actionFunction name="loadDetails" action="{!fetchEmployeeById}" rerender="EmployeeDetails">
                                <apex:param name="empId" value="{!empId}" assignTo="{!empId}" />
                            </apex:actionFunction>
                        </apex:actionRegion>

                        
                        <div id="employeeDetails">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="employeeDetails" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(employee))}">
                                <h2>employee Details</h2>
                                <p><strong>Name:</strong> {!employee.Name}</p>
                                <p><strong>ID:</strong> {!employee.Id}</p>
                            </apex:outputPanel>

                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ISNULL(employee)}">
                                <p>No employee found with the given Id.</p>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </div>
                    </apex:form>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openModal(empId) { 
            loadEmployeeDetails(empId);

            // Display the modal
            document.getElementById("modalOverlay").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeModal() {
            document.getElementById("modalOverlay").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</apex:component>

APEX Controller:
public with sharing class employeeController {

    public String empId { get; set; }
    public Employee__c employee { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Employee__c fetchEmployeeById() { 
        System.debug('empId: ' + empId);

        if (empId != null) {
            try {
                employee = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id = :empId];
                System.debug('employee fetched: ' + employee);
                return employee;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error fetching employee: ' + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            System.debug('empId is null');
            return null;
        }
    }
}


as i see it, your actionFunction has nothing telling it to run; see VF doc - try immediate = true
